# Crystal Report in ASP.NET - display image

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using a Crystal Report on my website to dynamically build a PDF file for download.  This is working great.  However, now I want to add an image to the report.  When I go to Insert - Picture, browse to my image file, and click OK nothing happens, which leads me to believe that I'm adding it incorrectly.  How can I do this?  Also, does the image need to exist on my web server or is it imbedded in the report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're adding the picture to the report through the Crystal Reports designer?

Possibly the picture is in an unsupported format?  Try saving it into another format and add it again, might just work!

As far as I'm aware, the image will be embedded into the report.

Comment: DOH!  I was trying to use a GIF.  Converted to PNG and it worked!

Comment: That's for sure.  It just did nothing!  Crystal is very powerful and it was easy to do what I was doing with it, but it has a ton of WTF moments.